# how to call notifyDataSetChanged() from a fragment?

Tags: android

I have a viewpager and a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for this, and a fragment class called Myfrag.
I want call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a object of Myfrag ,  how to call?

Answer (score 2):

adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Call this function whenever u need to update the list.

Answer (score 0):

So?

```
    FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i do this but fragments does not changs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) or even [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to notify the adapter of this change, or you can even create an interface to set a callback from within the fragment. Something like this:

```
public interface IAdapterNotifer {
  public void refreshAdapter();
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  private IAdapterNotifier notifier;

  public void setNotifier(IAdapterNotifier notifier) {
    this.notifier = notifier;
  }

  // call notifier.refreshAdapter when you want to refresh it
}

public MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements IAdapterNotifier {

  public void refreshAdapter() {
    notifiyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i do not know any thing about interface,when i call setNotifier(), what am i supposed to pass in it?, there is other way to call notifiyDataSetChanged ?

Comment: pass the adapter as the notifier because it implements IAdapterNotifier